# How to calculate a value for each row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input dataframe (created from a hive table) containing more than 100 rows. For each row of the dataframe, I need to extract the column values (most strings) and pass those values to a user-defined function. For each row, the function uses these input values and other intermediate dataframes (created from hive tables) to calculate a set of rows and stores in a result dataframe. 
How do I achieve this - please help.

I tried this:

```
var df1= hiveContext.sql("Select event_date,channelcode,st,tc,startsec,endsec from program_master")
var count1=df1.count()
df1 = df1.withColumn("INDEX", monotonically_increasing_id())
var i=1
while (i <= count1){
  var ed = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(to_date(unix_timestamp(df1("ed"), "dd-MM-yy").cast(TimestampType)).cast(DateType)).first().getDate(0)
  var cc = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(df1("cc")).first().getInt(0)
  var ST = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(df1("ST")).first().getString(0)
  var TC = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(df1("TC")).first().getString(0)
  var ss = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(df1("ss")).first().getInt(0)
  var es = df1.filter(df1("INDEX") === s"""$i""").select(df1("es")).first().getInt(0)
  calculate_values(ed, cc, st, tc, ss, ss, sparkSession)
  i=i+1
}
```

calculate_values def

```
def calculate_values(ed: Date,cc:Integer,ST:String,TC:String,ss:Integer,ss:Integer,sparkSession: SparkSession):Unit=
```

2 problems in what I tried: hence do not have an output
line 3: I expected it to give numbers like 1,2,3,......100.... to iterate using i - but its generating random very large numbers. 
line 5: It throws java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator

Comment: please share what you've tried so far? and some sample input and expected output. But before that clarify your requirement

Comment: Added the code and details that causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`monotonically_increasing_id()` will generate random numbers but in increasing manner, so you cannot rely on it to generate serial numbers as `row_number()` function**. But `row_number()` is expensive to be used on whole dataset as it will collect all the data in one executor unless you use `row_number()` by grouping the data.

**`monotonically_increasing_id()` would be helpful in cases where you want to order/sort your data.**

It seems that you are trying to calculate some values row by row using *event_date*, *channelcode*, *st*, *tc*, *startsec* and *endsec*.

If its a row by row calculation then I would suggest you to use a `udf` function. So you can convert your `calculate_value` function into a `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def calculate_value = udf((ed: Date,cc:Int,ST:String,TC:String,ss:Int,es:Int) => //write your calculation part here)
```

And you call the `udf` function using `withColumn` as

```
df1.withColumn("calculated", calculate(col("ed"), col("cc"), col("ST"), col("TC"), col("ss"), col("es"))
```

a new column will be created with the calculated value

But if the calculations can be done column wise I would recommend you to look at [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) too

Comment: Thank you. In the calculate_values function, I actually have to populate a result dataframe (this I defined as global dataframe - so that I can add using union in each iteration) because for each row of the input dataframe, a set of rows will be formed that I need to save and use later in the code.
Using your method, can I do this in my calculate function?

Comment: yes definitely. the way I have suggested with give you a new column with row by row calculated value and if you want a separete dataframe then you can select that column only into a new dataframe. Try it. And if the answer is helpful, which I am sure it is, you can upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: one more question - is it a problem in using the while loop as I have used? say, instead of monotonically_increasing_id(), I use row_number() and get the index.
The reason I'm asking is in later part of code, I may have more loops that will have a tricky situation: Each loop iteration of one row produces a result that will be used in the next iteration. The kind of while loop that I wrote was also designed keeping this in mind.

Comment: You can definitely write it. Theres no problem with that. But using inbuilt function would be much efficient. If you want to previous rows values then you can use lag function and there many more inbuilt functions you can benefit from.